# Why has there been no reduction in reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, voting, down-votes

In [What is reputation?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) it states that you lose reputation by 2 when your answer is voted down and you gain reputation by 10 when your answer is voted up.

However, [this answer from a new contributor](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/27481/7604) has been voted down and voted up, which to my calculations should lead to a reputation of 9:

- new user: +1
- answer voted up: +10
- answer voted down: -2
- add the above together: +9

Yet, the user has a reputation of 11 and this is their only post.

How is this? Is it possibly because the vote down may have been before the vote up?

> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1.

If that is the case, OK, you cannot drop below 1, but surely any votes down should still have been taken into account when you receive any upvotes? If there are 2 votes down then 1 vote up, you can have an answer of -1 but still have reputation of 11 yet you would have -7 the other way? This to me is counterintuitive to policy of voting down in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisRogers From the answer to that linked FAQ: *"No user's reputation may drop below one point; if an action would cause a user's reputation to drop below one point, that user only loses enough reputation to drop to one point (source), and __the remaining penalty or loss is waived__."* And again in the bottom of that answer: *"No reputation is required to make posts, and the rep loss from downvotes is waived if it causes your reputation to drop below 1."*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reputation can not be reduced below 1, so when you receive a downvote at 1 reputation, you do not go into negative.

So the sequence of events here was:

1. Start at 1 reputation
2. Received a downvote. No reputation lost since they're at the minimum.
3. Received an upvote. +10 reputation.