# Please edit reputation system to account for previous votes down after receiving first vote up with new contributors

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, down-votes, user-accounts

As discussed in [Why has there been no reduction in reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368764/349643) you cannot go below 1 in reputation, but when receiving the first vote up after receiving votes down, the reputation does not take into account the previous votes down.

> OK, you cannot drop below 1, but surely any votes down should still have been taken into account when you receive any upvotes? If there are 2 votes down then 1 vote up, you can have an answer of -1 but still have reputation of 11 yet you would have -7 the other way? This to me is counterintuitive to policy of voting down in the first place.

The overall reputation within the site should reflect their overall votes on questions and answers, not the votes after their first vote up.

@Glorfindel said in his answer,

> try to put yourself in the shoes of a new user who asked a couple of bad, downvoted questions. After hanging around a bit more, they finally get a feel for how the site works and they start to post something valuable (a question or answer, doesn't matter). Now what would be more discouraging than getting an upvote (hey, somebody appreciated my content!) and discovering that it doesn't get reflected in your reputation

OK so you got the feel of the site and see the error of your ways. <strike>Delete your negative score question/answer and retrieve your rep scores, or</strike> Edit it to receive more votes up or even vote down retractions. You may have made a mistake but mistakes can be corrected.

Comment: Related: [Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/294055)

Comment: I disagree. Per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287053/377214: *[The current system] is actually great for new users. It means that, if your first question is poor and receives downvotes, they do not hurt you but if you fix the question and it gets upvotes after, you still get the reward of having fixed your post. It may still show a negative overall value but your rep will be higher in the end.*

Comment: "*The overall reputation within the site should reflect their overall votes on questions and answers, not the votes after their first vote up.*" it does reflect it. Not *exactly* but it's close enough. The rep might be off by, what, 2-4 points for most cases a user *did* receive downvotes when they were at the minimum? Does that *really matter*?

Comment: Re *"the reputation does not take into account the previous votes down."*: I don't think that is true at all. E.g., if there is a recalculation of total reputation points, why would that calculation depend on the order of votes used in the calculation? The time at which at vote was cast shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/349643) which explains that it does and give the reason why, which is counterintuitive in my view

Comment: @Chris Rogers: I don't know what you are referring to. Can you quote directly? If it is *"the remaining penalty or loss is waived."* it might be a misinterpretation of how it may actually work (test for a result below 1 reputation point at the very end of the reputation points (re)calculation). A direct reference to how the reputation points (re)calculation works would be better.

Comment: Why not just propose negative reputation instead of hiding their reputation debt from a new user until their first upvote? How does a cumulative reputation score instead of limiting the amount of reputation you can lose to the reputation you’ve earned help the site? I don’t think it’s a good idea to allow users to make one misstep and end up having to pay off hundreds of points of reputation debt before they’re allowed back in chat for example.

Comment: Deleting a heavily downvoted question doesn't make the badness go away, it just hides it. Deleted questions are counted in the question-ban algorithm. Ideally, the OP should improve the question, but in reality many bad questions from new OPs aren't salvageable.

Answer (score 19):

It would make sense from a mathematical perspective.

However, try to put yourself in the shoes of a new user who asked a couple of bad, downvoted questions. After hanging around a bit more, they finally get a feel for how the site works and they start to post something valuable (a question or answer, doesn't matter). Now what would be more discouraging than getting an upvote (hey, somebody appreciated my content!) and discovering that it doesn't get reflected in your reputation? If the system would behave like that, it would be an incentive to *leave* (at least for me), at the *very moment* they start to contribute positively. IMHO that's a not good idea *at all* ...

Comment: OK so you got the feel of the site and see the error of your ways. Delete your negative score answer and retrieve your rep scores or edit it to receive votes up. You may have made a mistake but mistakes can be corrected.

Comment: That may work for answers, but most of the times new users post *questions*, and they cannot be deleted (by their author) if there are positively scoring answers.

Comment: @ChrisRogers  Besides, doesn't deleting downvoted content count towards the question/answer ban?

Comment: @Glorfindel A relatively minor point is that a question author also can't delete their own question if it has more than 1 non-deleted answer, or if an answer is accepted (but the author obviously can unaccept to avoid this issue).

Comment: It would be an incentive for burner accounts as well. We got enough headaches from those already.

Comment: OTOH, how does a new user feel who asked a good question, got an upvote, and spots tbat a user asked a couple of useless mega-dupes and still gets more rep from a further good question?

Comment: @MartinJames I suspect that the counter to that is that reputation isn't supposed to be a "comparison metric". Reputation is designed as "a measure of trust"; reputation unlocks privileges for individual users, and is displayed as a sort of "badge of honor", but having more or less reputation than another user isn't really useful for anything of note... I suspect that's largely why it isn't really used for comparisons on any page other than [leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta/2021-01-01/) (Which is kinda hidden away anyways).

Comment: Put another way; reputation amount is ultimately measured by `https://${site}/help/privileges`, rather than against peers' scores. That doesn't necessarily change how a user might *feel*, but I think that's a little irrelevant if they're just interpreting the meaning of reputation incorrectly.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a good idea to encourage users to abandon an account and create a fresh one instead of working to improve their contributions, which is exactly what allowing a user to accrue reputation debt would do.

If my account is at -50 points, why would I fix the existing content instead of creating a new account and start fresh at 1 point? If you hide the debt from me by deducting it from future upvotes instead of displaying it as -50, well, that’s just mean and more likely to make me want to quit than work off that debt. Or I’ll just make a new account every time I want to post something until I finally manage to contribute something that gets me a good chunk of reputation.

Reputation isn’t a score, it’s made-up currency that is only worth something on the network. Allowing a user to go into reputation debt that they have to pay back before they can start earning reputation toward privileges doesn’t benefit the site in any way. A user should never end up more disadvantaged when it comes to earning privileges than a brand new user.